# Preserve line breaks when pasting into textarea

Tags: html, textarea

I have a textarea. When I paste text with line breaks into it, the line breaks are automatically removed. But when I manually enter line breaks (hitting carraige return), they are preserved.

How do I force the textarea to preserve line breaks with pasted text?

Answer (score 11):

Don't know if this applies to all browsers, but in Google Chrome (6 and 7), line breaks in pasted text gets removed if the textarea's style is set to `white-space: nowrap;`.

I used this style setting to prevent the default wrapping of long lines and experienced the same problem as yours. Later I realized that setting the textarea attribute `wrap` to `off` does a much better job. Be aware that `wrap="off"` is [widely supported but not standardized](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/textarea).

Answer (score 0):

The line breaks are always preserved when pasted on textarea.

Maybe the source have a different line break, you are copying from what program?