# copy paste table to chrome, textarea.value no new lines

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, textarea, newline

try this in chrome (ff,ie works ok):
in msword or writer make a 3 row table. In each row put something, select all rows and copy paste to chrome textarea. Each row is now in new line but when you check textarea.value there is no new lines ..strange even spliting by \n or \r not working
textarea.value always return one line output

any ideas?

i'm trying to split textarea.value by new lines but not working
textarea.value.split('\n');

Comment: Works for me splitting on \n.

Comment: did you follow my instructions (pasting from table)? entering new lines by hand results in the correct value

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356399/preserve-line-breaks-when-pasting-into-textarea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

found the problem white-space:nowrap; was causing this :P